# Fetch from upstream and undo all commits I have in origin

Tags: git

I have a fork of an upstream project which requires to be fully aligned with the source code in upstream.
I have issued a

```
git fetch upstream
```

So now I've fetched all data from the upstream project but when I commit a change, some conflicts arise from older commits I have done in the past.
As I understand, as further step I should:

```
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
```

is it correct? any simpler way to make **origin=upstream**, destroying any commit I have done in my fork? (Just like I have forked now the upstream project)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Find the nearest fork point commit

```
git merge-base upstream/master origin/master
```

For example, the result is `55c16639a7a7a8c474b9aa448ab112086738de6f` or for short `55c1663`

**(2)** Reset origin source to `55c1663`

```
git reset --hard 55c1663
```

**(3)** Fetch and Merge

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master --no-ff
```

See more at https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have verified your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
git branch --create-reflog -f master -t upstream/master
```

Make sure you aren't on master (you're on another branch) or it will fail.

If you're on master, you can use `reset`:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

If you have uncommitted changes, be sure to `git stash` them or they're lost. You can do `git stash pop` after performing the hard reset to restore your uncommitted changes.

Comment: This will destroy all of the local changes in the fork

Comment: @RobbieAverill I addressed that.